# Git push in aws code pipeline script is not working

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

We are trying to update the Git tag versions using below script.

https://github.com/bellwethercoffee-sw/tagpipeline/blob/main/git_tagging.sh

But git push is failing as its using codestar connection to bitbucket.

buldspec file

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        java: corretto11
    commands:
      - echo "https://$GIT_USER:$GIT_PASS@bitbucket.org" > ~/.git-credentials
      - git config --global --replace-all credential.helper 'store'
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - mvn -q -s settings.xml test
      - git config --global user.email "test@test.com"
      - bash git_tagging.sh
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the jar file
      ....
```

Am getting below error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://codestar-connections.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com': No such device or address
```

Comment: how did you solve it?